estoy intentando volver de una ventana a otra en java con un boton llamado cancelar, como puedo hacerlo
Tengo un JFrame form llamado VistaHabitaciones y otro llamado VistaPrincipal, y una clase ControladorHabitaciones(para la VistaHabitaciones) y otra clase llamada ControladorPrincipal( para la vista Principal, desde la vista principal se abre la de vista habitaciones pero no puedo volver de la habitaciones a la principal, como puedo resolver este error, agradeceria mucho su ayuda
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    VistaPrincipal vprincipal = new VistaPrincipal();
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals(modelo.getVista().btnCancelar)){
        vprincipal.setVisible(true);
        modelo.getVista().dispose();
      
    }
  
}


modelo.getVista() suena muy mal, un modelo no debe saber de la vista. Lo correcto es que el evento click del botón cierre la ventana y en consecuencia se dispare un evento close que debe cachar la ventana principal, la cual puede preguntar a su ventana hija (habitaciones) por su último estado (cancelada). En la vista principal deberías hacer algo como vistaHabitaciones.addWindowListener(this).

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

NO se ve el código, ponlo como texto no como imagen por favor

No estoy seguro de lo que hace tu código, pero creo que te puede servir lo siguiente:
VistaHabitaciones vhabitaciones = new VistaHabitaciones();
VistaPrincipal vprincipal = new VistaPrincipal();
boolean principalEsVisible = false;
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
   if( e.getActionCommand().equals( modelo.getVista().btnCancelar )) {
      if( principalEsVisible ) {
         vprincipal.setVisible( false );
         vhabitaciones.setVisible( true );
         principalEsVisible = false;
      }
      else {
         vprincipal.setVisible( true );
         vhabitaciones.setVisible( false );
         principalEsVisible = true;
      }      
   }  
}

Como puedes ver, en base al estado de principalEsVisible, definimos cual frame se ve.
